# Bash script not echoing new lines in echo subprocess

Tags: bash, echo, subshell

When I run this script on my terminal it works perfectly with the newline

```
echo -e $(echo "a \na")
```

Outputs:

```
a 
a
```

When I wrap this up in a bash script -  test.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo -e $(echo "a \na")
```

And I call ./test.sh, I get this output:

```
-e a a
```

How can I make the bash script give the same output with the newline as running directly on the terminal?

Comment: Make the shebang `#!/bin/bash`, otherwise it's a sh script and not a bash script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `printf`. The `echo` isn't portable. Some shells doesn't knows the `-e` and like. Also, using `printf` you will get more formatting options.

```
printf "%s\n%s\n" a a
#or
printf "a\na\n"
```

The answer to your question is in the [@that other guy's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1899640/that-other-guy) comment:

> Make the shebang #!/bin/bash, otherwise it's a sh script and not a
>   bash script

e.g.

```
sh test.sh
# -e a a
bash test.sh
# a
# a
dash test.sh
# -e a a
zsh test.sh
# a a
```

so... use `printf` - will work everywhere and give the same result.